# how do I break a paragraph typing animation in CSS to continue animation on the next line?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Currently my typing animation runs to the right and does not break to the next line, so most of the text is not visible once it runs off the page.

I tried adding a line break tag within the text but this would run the animation individually on each separate line after the line break rather than fluidly.

As mentioned, currently the text runs off the page. I tried changing the overflow, messing with margins, and wrapping. I want the typing animation to write one line and then continue with the next one.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Waiting for the Sunrise', cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 10px 50px;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.typed {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: pre;
  width: 0;
  animation: typing;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-timing-function: steps(338, end);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
  to {
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Waiting+for+the+Sunrise" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<body>
  <div id="typedtext"></div>
</body>

<div class="container">
  <p class="typed">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, you have content outside the head and body elements. That's not valid HTML.

Comment: read this: https://dev.to/afif/a-multi-line-css-only-typewriter-effect-3op3

Comment: The [typed.js](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js) library gives you lots of flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Getting styles to wrap around line breaks has been notoriously challenging since the beginning.

It isn't what you asked for, but I'd consider writing the text to the element with JavaScript instead. It wouldn't take much more code than you have in styles.

```js
const textEl = document.querySelector('.typed');
const textArray = textEl.dataset.text.split('');

// there's probably a more performant way to do this, but....
textArray.forEach((char, i) => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    textEl.append(char);
  }, i * 100);
});
```

```css
.container {
  font-family: 'Waiting for the Sunrise', cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 10px 50px;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Waiting+for+the+Sunrise" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="typed" data-text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"></p>
  </div>
</body>
```